# How to decode URL from JS in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, urlencode

Currently working on old mobile project. The main problem is that i receive a parameter via `GET` method which is for example an `a` char and JS automatically encodes it (i am building url on click from the field value and do redirect because AJAX is not supported and i can't use forms.) like`%D0%B0` and so PHP cant't decode it via `urldecode` function. Is there a way to decode it?

Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById('search-button').onclick = function() {
        window.location = site_url + 'sites/search/' + document.getElementById('search-input').value;
    }
```

Also tried to add `encodeURI`.

**UPDATE:**

The problem was in keyboard layout. It was russian and a looks the same in both english and russian.

Comment: How are you building it? (Whatever you are doing, you probably aren't doing it right as you shouldn't need to manually decode it in PHP, `$_GET` should do it for you).

Comment: @Quentin - just added example.

Answer (score 0):

try using `decodeURIComponent(url)` function that might work.